# How to stop pending TASK execution when current task failed?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a list of task that executes one at a time my problem is how can I stop the pending task when the current task failed?

Here is my code:

```
if(await App.TodoManager.CheckContactsData(host, database, domain, contact) != 'failed)'{
     if(await App.TodoManager.CheckRetailerOutletData(contact)){
            //And so on
     }
}
```

What I am trying to do I want to add some kind of checking if the task has been executed successfully :

```
if(await App.TodoManager.CheckContactsData(host, database, domain, contact) == "ok"){
    //execute another task then check again if the task ok then proceed until the end of the task
}
```

Here is my sample Task when the retry variable is equals to FALSE the pending task should not be executed:

```
public async Task CheckContactsData(string contact)
{
    try
    {
        var getcontactschanges = Constants.conn.QueryAsync<ContactsTable>("SELECT * FROM tblContacts WHERE Supervisor = ? AND LastUpdated > LastSync AND Deleted != '1'", contact);
        var contactchangesresultCount = getcontactschanges.Result.Count;

        Preferences.Set("contactschanges", contactchangesresultCount.ToString(), "private_prefs");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Crashes.TrackError(ex);
        var retry = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Checking Retailer Error", "Checking retailer failed.\n\nDo you want to retry? \n\n Error:\n\n" + ex.Message, "Yes", "No");

        if (retry)
        {
            await CheckContactsData(contact);
        }
        else {
            //Pending task should be stop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define a `CancellationTokenSource` in your `App.TodoManager`. Verify the `IsCancellationRequested` before you want to open a new task. Any of your tasks fails, call the cancel method of the `CancellationTokenSource` to avoid the new task's starting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way

```
//for Task cancellation
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

await App.TodoManager.CheckContactsData(host, database, domain, contact,tokenSource);
await App.TodoManager.CheckRetailerOutletData(contact,tokenSource);
await App.TodoManager.CheckCAFData(contact,tokenSource);
await App.TodoManager.CheckCAFActivityData(contact,tokenSource);
await App.TodoManager.CheckEmailRecipientData(contact,tokenSource);
```

You have to add a new parameter of type CancellationTokenSource in every method.

```
public async Task CheckContactsData(string contact,CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    try
    {
        var getcontactschanges = Constants.conn.QueryAsync<ContactsTable>("SELECT * FROM tblContacts WHERE Supervisor = ? AND LastUpdated > LastSync AND Deleted != '1'", contact);
        var contactchangesresultCount = getcontactschanges.Result.Count;

        Preferences.Set("contactschanges", contactchangesresultCount.ToString(), "private_prefs");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        cts.Cancle();
        Crashes.TrackError(ex);
        var retry = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Checking Retailer Error", "Checking retailer failed.\n\nDo you want to retry? \n\n Error:\n\n" + ex.Message, "Yes", "No");

        if (retry)
        {
            await CheckContactsData(contact);
        }
        else {
            //Pending task should be stop
        }
    }
}
```

Then you have to call `cts.Cancle();` in every `catch`,

Then you can check like

```
if(!tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested){
    //execute another task then check again if the task ok then proceed until the end of the task
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: where do I put "if(!tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)"? and what do I put inside?

Comment: why you have added `if(await App.TodoManager.CheckContactsData(host, database, domain, contact) == "ok"`

Comment: you can replace `if(await App.TodoManager.CheckContactsData(host, database, domain, contact) == "ok"` with `if(!tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)`

Comment: No its just a representation of what I am trying to do

Comment: do I put all of my Task inside if(!tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)?

Comment: or 1 task 1 if?

Comment: Your task is dependent on each other?

Comment: if there is dependency then we have to decide where we need to cancel task

Comment: Yes my task is dependent on each other how can I do it?